# List the current folder folder's sizes with the terminal?

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal

I want a list of the folders from the current directory or one that I specify with their size.

I have tried with du but I only get the size of the directories I specify (du . ./f1), and ls doesn't show the size of the folders.

How do I do this without any scripting ?

Comment: Thanks ;-) but I've already tried and couldn't find anything. And try Googling du!

Comment: Time changes everything I guess. Now googling `du` gives stackoverflow answers :D

Answer (score 294, accepted):

If you want to show all the directories in the current directory:

```
$ du -sh */
788K    foo/
500K    bar/
931K    baz/
```

To show them starting from another directory:

```
$ du -sh /path/to/dir/*/
48K     /path/to/dir/dir1/
4.0K    /path/to/dir/dir2/
6.7M    /path/to/dir/dir3/
20K     /path/to/dir/dir4/
8.0K    /path/to/dir/dir5/
44K     /path/to/dir/dir6/
```

If you want to make sure directories with names starting with a dot are included do `shopt -s dotglob` first.

Comment: Thanks all great answers but this one is the simplest one.

I forgot the ending / in my tests.

Comment: Where -s means summarise, display the total and -h means human readable

Comment: Sort folders by size: `du -s */ | sort -n`.

Comment: @AntonTarasenko: [Sort human readable sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213288/human-readable-recursive-sorted-list-of-largest-files/5213618#5213618)

Comment: Including hidden (dot) directories: https://askubuntu.com/a/356915/176799

Comment: @AntonTarasenko: `shopt -s dotglob` [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

Comment: `-n` does not sorts properly use `du -sh */ | sort -hr` instead

Comment: `du -sh *` is perfectly running. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 25):

On a Mac, the --max-depth option is supplanted by -d [depth].  So, to see a human readable listing of your root drive plus 2 levels deep use the following:

```
du -hd 2 /*
```

Note:  this command will expose the top two directory levels off your root.  *This includes traversing one level into your Volumes*, and will list the summary sizes of each top-level directory in each of your attached volumes.  Depending on what you have attached, this command could take some time to complete.

Answer (score 20):

Another aproach is the --max-depth option.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 .
```

Will list all directories and files under the current folder with size.

Depth 2 would list one more level of folders.

Comment: On Mac, it's `du -hd 2 .` for 2 levels of depth.

Comment: Ah yes. And probably on FreeBSD as well. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$ du -s ./f1
```

or

```
$ du -sh ./f1
```

for more friendly readable sizes.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the accepted answer, this command will show you the sizes of the folders in the directory, *and* will also list them by size for you to interpret easier:

```
$ du -sh */ | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 4):

On Mac, you can install the GNU (Linux) implementation of `du` with Homebrew (`brew install coreutils`). 
Then for example:

```
gdu folder -shL --exclude=.git
```

where

- `gdu` is the name given to the GNU implementation of `du` (by default Homebrew does not hide `/usr/bin/du`);
- `s` produces a grand total for the folder specified (omit if you want to see the breakdown);
- `h` outputs human-readable sizes;
- `L` follows symlinks;
- `--exclude=.git` excludes the git directory within the specified folder (this is just an example).

You can ignore more folders by adding `--exclude=blah`. You can also specify several folders at once (ie `gdu folder1 folder2 ...`), and in that case, you can combine all the subtotals into a single size using option `c`.

Answer (score 4):

I like the following approach:

```
du -schx .[!.]* * | sort -h
```

where:

- `s`:  display only a total for each argument
- `c`:  produce a grand total
- `h`:  print sizes in a human-readable format
- `x`:  skip directories on different file systems
- `.[!.]* *`: Summarize disk usage of each file, recursively for directories (including "hidden" ones)
- `| sort -h`: Sort based on human-readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

Comment: I just needed to add the `-r` to the sort to have it give me it in descending order.

Comment: this is the best answer as it takes into account also files in the current folder and not only subfolders.

Answer (score 3):

`$ du --max-depth=1 /var/www/ | sort -n -r`

Comment: When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is good practice to explain how your answer is different and include some explanation so that it isn't a command only answer.

Comment: Can you expand yourt answer to explain what the parameters do?

Answer (score 3):

Worth to mention the [NCurses Disk Usage](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) shell command.

> Ncdu is a disk usage analyzer with an ncurses interface. It is
>   designed to find space hogs on a remote server where you don't have an
>   entire graphical setup available, but it is a useful tool even on
>   regular desktop systems. Ncdu aims to be fast, simple and easy to use,
>   and should be able to run in any minimal POSIX-like environment with
>   ncurses installed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a POSIX script that will work with:

- A file
- Files
- A directory
- Directories

```r
#!/bin/sh
ls -ARgo "$@" | awk '{q += $3} END {print q}'
```

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/stdlib/blob/7696c9c/contrib/file-size.sh)